# Asignar colores a usuarios sin repetir color python

Tags: python, random

llevo 1 dia intentando resolver esto en Python:

-Asignar colores a cada usuario de manera aleatoria.

-No repetir color en ningún jugador.

-El color debe ser almacenado en el diccionario de cada jugador, añadiendo la clave 'Color'.

-Mostrar el resultado de la asignación de color en cada jugador.

-Tengo que usar random.randint

```
import random
colores=["amarillo","azul","verde","rojo"]
usuarios2=[
    {"Nombre":"Josep",
     "color":colores[random.randint(0,3)]},
    {"Nombre":"Claudio",
     "color":colores[random.randint(0,3)]},
    {'Nombre':'Isabel',
     "color":colores[random.randint(0,3)]},
    {'Nombre':'Sheila',
     "color":colores[random.randint(0,3)]}
    ]

for i in usuarios2:
    print(i)
```

Gracias por anticipado.

Comment: Deberías eliminar el color de la lista una vez que lo asignas. Eso evitara repeticiones. También reemplaza el `randint(0,3)` por `randint(len(colores))`.

Comment: Hola Moe. Gracias por la respuesta, pero al sustituir (0,3) por len(colores) me da error porque randint requiere 2 argumentos. Otra cosa, elimino un color una vez que lo asigno?

Comment: Muchas gracias Candid Moe

Answer (score 1):

Como bien ha dicho Candid Moe en los comentarios, solo bastaría con eliminar el color asignado de la lista para evitar repeticiones. Lo único con lo que debería tenerse cuidado es con tener siempre el mismo número de colores que de usuarios. Aquí el código:

```
import random
colores=["amarillo","azul","verde","rojo"]
usuarios2=[
    {"Nombre":"Josep"},
    {"Nombre":"Claudio"},
    {'Nombre':'Isabel'},
    {'Nombre':'Sheila'}
    ]

for usuario in usuarios2:
    color = colores[random.randint(0, len(colores) - 1)]
    usuario["color"] = color
    colores.remove(color)

for i in usuarios2:
    print(i)
```

Comment: leonjuancarlos. Muchas gracias. Ahora si que va.